# Substring not working on returned ajax data object field

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am not sure why this isn't working but the returned value for CellPhone is in the format `9999999999`

I need to inject dashes into it so that it's `999-999-9999` so I tried this:

```
$("#member-cellPhone-value").html(data[0].CellPhone.substring(0, 2) + '-' + data[0].CellPhone.substring(3, 5) + '-' + data[0].CellPhone.substring(6,9));
```

When the page renders it's actually rendering nothing.  But if I just do a strict data[0].CellPhone alone it does render the 9999999999 format

so in other words my attempt to add those dashes is not working and in fact hiding the value altogether

Comment: Maybe it's number? Did you try `CellPhone.toString().substring(0, 2)`?

Answer (score 2):

Check if `data[0].CellPhone` has a value and its a *string* not a **number**.

Answer (score 2):

First ensure `data[0].CellPhone` is of type string. If not you can convert it to string by `data[0].CellPhone.toString()`

Second your logic for splitting is wrong it should be as below

```
x.substring(0,3) + '-' + x.substring(3, 6) + '-' + x.substring(6,10)
```

where `x` is the variable containing the phone number as string.

Answer (score 1):

As everyone is saying, make sure you `.toString()`, definitely sounds like it's typeof *number*.

Another way of getting the digits is just using a simple regex `.match()`, I think it makes it more readable when you're putting the numbers into your html also.

```
var p = data[0].CellPhone.toString().match(/(\d{3})(\d{3})(\d{4})/);

$("#member-cellPhone-value").html(p[1] '-' + p[2] + '-' + p[3]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this with simple js

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var phonenum = '9999999999'; 
var phone= phonenum.substring(0, 2) + '-' + phonenum.substring(3, 5) + '-' +      phonenum.substring(6,9);
alert(phone);

</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var number = '9999999999';
var changedNumber = number.replace(/(\d{3})(\d{3})(\d{4})/, "$1-$2-$3");

alert(number);
</script>
```